# Is it Possible to draw two separate quad using G_TRIANGLE_FAN or GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP?

Tags: c++, opengl

Is it possible? if I had 8 vertices from 2  quad with separate location(quad based),is it possible to draw two of this quad with single one call to glDrawElement?

Comment: No. They both [use shared vertexes](http://tfc.duke.free.fr/old/models/images/05.gif). What you suggest is kind of the exact opposite of what they are meant for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use degenerate triangles (triangle which area is 0) or [primitive restart](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart).

Comment: Interesting -- I thought of degenerate triangles but decided not to pursue it any further. Are there performance penalties with these methods?

Comment: Degenerate triangle have almost full cost, so their extensive use will result in lower performance than indexed triangles list. With small amount of degenerate triangles it should be ok. Unfortunately I don't know primitive restart performance penalty, but it shouldn't be high.

Comment: You can also use `glMultiDrawElements` to draw seperated primitives with a single call.